# Is transpose a change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, duality-theorems

Does it exist $P,Q \in \mathbb K^n$ such that for all $A \in \mathbb K^n : 
                       A^T = PAQ$

I suppose it is not, but how to find a contradiction ? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $M_n(\Bbb K)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $n>1$ of course.

Set $A=I$ to get $Q=P^{-1}$. Since $\phi(A)=PAP^{-1}$ is an automorphism (i.e it satisfies the identity $\phi(AB)=\phi(A)\phi(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$) and $\psi(A)=A^T$ is an antiautomorphism (i.e. it satisfies the identity $\phi(AB)=\phi(B)\phi(A)$ for all $A$ and $B$), the only way they can be equal is if $M_n(\Bbb K)$ is commutative. But whenever $\mathbb{K}$ is a ring with unity this is impossible, since

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: @Lucas You mean invertible? Setting $A=I$ gives $I=PQ$, so $P$ and $Q$ would have to be inverses (hence invertible).

Comment: @Lucas If $PQ=I$  then $P$ and $Q$ are invertible, then left-multiplying by $P^{-1}$ gives $Q=P^{-1}$ and right-multiplying by $P$ gives $QP=I$. (Not sure why you want $QP=I$ but whatever.)